# What scholars disagree with Michael Heiser?

Tags: gods, nephilim

Michael S. Heiser has a podcast and a number of books mostly on heavenly beings, and makes a number of extraordinary claims.  Among them:

- In Psalm 82, the psalmist writes that God renders judgement among the gods - and Heiser claims these are other heavenly beings, probably the gods of the surrounding nations.
- Heiser supports the historicity of 1st Enoch (at least, in broad strokes.  I don't recall him endorsing it explicitly, but he mentions it a lot).  Demons are thus the disembodied spirits of the Nephilim which don't have anywhere to go.
- Heiser claims that the world is overseen by heavenly beings, each with their own nation to look after - and that all of them are doing a poor job (apart from God Himself).

I might have some of it wrong - I've only started listening to/reading his works.

My question, therefore, is: Who disagrees with Heiser and has published a reputable rebuttal?  His conclusions seem unobjectionable from what he brings up, so I want to make sure it's not just a matter of him skipping over things that disagree or misrepresenting the solidity of his premises.  Is he merely revealing the obvious when we actually look at everything the Bible says about heavenly beings?

I want to be clear that I neither support Heiser (though some of his conclusions mesh well with my previous convictions) nor oppose him at this juncture; I merely want to understand better.

Comment: You might find the following article regarding Michael Heiser's take on Psalm 82 informative. https://calvarychristianfellowship.com/a-reason-for-hope-question-of-the-week-august-28th-2020/  I personally agree with the article that Psalm 82 is about men has human judges, not "Gods." I do agree with Mr. Heiser on his take about the "angel of the Lord" in the Old Testament.

Comment: Heiser often times calls himself a sifter and admits that his theology is based on the works of others. He has definitely been inspired by Benjamin Sommer's book  "The Bodies of God and the World of Ancient Israel "(2009).